# Creating mesh at run-time

Tags: xna, c#, 3d-meshes

I've a set of voxel data and I want to create a mesh out of it at run-time.

I've looked into `MeshBuilder` and `MeshHelper` but I haven't found anything useful or a good tutorial how to use them. Can anyone tell me how to create a mesh at run-time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this should answer your question: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/4751/24616.aspx

Basically you should just create a vertex and index buffer yourself (you can wrap them up in a nice class that implements IDrawable ofc).

Once you have a vertex and index buffer you can draw your model like in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.indexbuffer.aspx):

```
VertexBuffer  vertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(GraphicsDevice, typeof(VertexPositionColor), 8, BufferUsage.None);

vertexBuffer.SetData<VertexPositionColor>(primitiveList);

IndexBuffer  lineListIndexBuffer = new IndexBuffer(
    GraphicsDevice,
    IndexElementSize.SixteenBits,
    sizeof(short) * lineListIndices.Length,
    BufferUsage.None);

lineListIndexBuffer.SetData<short>(lineListIndices);

GraphicsDevice.Indices = lineListIndexBuffer;
GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer);
GraphicsDevice.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.LineList, 0, 0, 8, 0, 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on 2D game 2y ago and had to draw shapes like thet. You could look what I have done [Project - Squared](https://github.com/AleksandarDev/Project-Squared).

Take a look at `GraphicsDrawer` class under `SquaredEngine.Graphics`, it will allow you to draw some basic meshes, triangles, lines, quads, ellipses, etc.

You could easily make this to work in 3D env.